# Why can't I send data to fabric from Iran?

Tags: analytics, crashlytics, fabric.io, google-fabric

It's been about a week or so that our clients can't send data to fabric in Iran, I wanted to know if this ban was made by the fabric and why now?

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Mahtabi. I think your question is so abroad for being response here. Could you reformulate your question for being more specific?

Comment: Same problem for me.

Comment: And it's programming problem how?

Comment: since fabric doesn't have a forum and the support email is not responding and when I click on the forum's icon in fabric's dashboard it takes me to google-fabric tag on SO, I'm asking it here. @zubergu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming. It is a support question you should be asking the vendor.

Comment: @zubergu I agree on closing this question; I have the same problem and I have contacted their support and waiting for response.

Comment: @MohammadMahtabi it could be due to the election coming up they have history of disturbing the network near election I have seen several problems when using some of google's products aswell.

Comment: Same for me. I'm looking at users information, exactly from April 18, the rate of new users and users activities decreased by half. Even recently users complaining about "Force Stop", but i did not receive any noticeable report. I sent a support email and will wait for their response.

Answer (score 5):

Todd from Fabric here. We're currently observing a drop-off in Answers events that we believe is related to end-users in Iran. We have no more details at this time.

Comment: Thanks, I also had same problem with answers events dropping, but it seems to be solved on May 7th. I'm 100% sure it was a problem with Iran's internet not reaching answers servers most of the times.